# Error /usr/bin/env: ‘python’: No such file or directory - installing presto on AWS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, presto

I unpacked the presto on AWS EC2 instance and followed the documentation on [prestodb](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/installation/deployment.html)
when I run `bin/launcher start`I get the following error:

> /usr/bin/env: ‘python’: No such file or directory

Comment: your ami type is of amazon linux or debian based?

Answer (score 0):

I guess documentation could mention that explicitly, but you need certain piece of software installed to run presto. This includes, but is not limited to:

- Supported Java JVM
- Python (i guess 2.7 would do)

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu/Debian:

Install Python if you did not do before:

```
apt-get install python3
```

If you have python already:

```
whereis python3

sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/pytho
```